# If $\partial A \subseteq L = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {{L_i}} \subseteq A$ then $\partial A = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^k {{L_i}} $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A,L_i\subset \mathbb{C}$ and

- $L = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n {{L_i}} $
- $\partial A \subseteq L \subseteq A$
- $\partial A$ is boundary of $A$.
- $A,L_i$ have  Euclidean topological.
- $L_i$ are
  suitable smooth curves and $A$ is algebraic curve.

Can we say that $\partial A = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^k {{L_i}} $, $k\le n$?

Comment: Are there any topological conditions about $A,L_i$ ? (Open sets, compact, etc ...)

Comment: @C.Dubussy - I edited this post.

Comment: @H.S Yes, everything is in the Euclidean topology, but do you know anything about $A$ and $L_i$? Are they open? closed? compact?

Comment: Without further conditions, we can't say that. $\partial A$ could be a proper subset of $L_1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I edited this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an algebraic curve, $A$ is closed and perfect. I.e. $\overline A = A$ and $A^o = \emptyset$. Since $A^o = A \setminus \partial A$ it must be that $A \subseteq \partial A \subseteq \overline A = A$. Therefore $\partial A = A$. Therefore $A \subseteq L \subseteq A$. I.e. $L = A$.

Comment: Why does, algebraic curve is closed?

Comment: Polynomials are continuous. $0$ is closed.